# python multithreading long thread running

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing program that search parallelly word in text. I have "problem" with running threads, because it takes the longest time in program. If there's more threads it takes less time for one to find word because the text block is divided between threads. But I tried to measure which part takes the most time and it's this part of starting threads.  Here's the code:

```
startThreadsStart=time.time()
for i in range(0,threads_number):
    threads.append(ParallelStringSearch("something", i)) 
    threads[i].start()
startThreadsEnd = time.time()-startThreadsStart
```

and the run() method in Thread class:

```
 def run(self):
    self.time = time.time()
    self.search()
    self.end_time = time.time()-self.time
    print "EXECUTION: ",self.index,self.end_time
```

Comment: how many threads are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using CPython, for parallelizing CPU-bound tasks, python threads wouldn't be able to help you, because of the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock).  Try subprocesses instead.

Comment: I'm using Jython that doesn't have GIL. But starting threads takes the longest time

Comment: I use startThreadsStart and startThreadsEnd to get time of running all threads. e.x I have 120 threads, for one it's about 0.0620000362396 to find word but all process of starting all 120 threads takes 0.317000150681

Comment: If there is more threads I should get less time of overall processing

Comment: For CPU-bound tasks, it makes no sense using more thread than number of CPUs.  There's overhead associated with starting them, and with context-switching between them.